# JAVA - Increment input number on Selenium with Keys

Tags: java, selenium, keyboard, increment

On my test, I want to simulate with Selenium, the "top arrow" increment.
For this, I've do this to begin : `myVar.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);`
Before the increment, the value is 0. After, the value is 1. I want to increment up 10, please. I don't want write my line code 10 times.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [*Edsger Dijkstra* once said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra#On_the_nature_of_computer_science_and_computer_programming):

> "*Two or more, use a for*" - Edsger Dijkstra

So you can simply write a `for` loop over the function call:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myVar.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_UP);
}
```